# Network throughput tester

Tags: windows, gratis, offline, networking

Can someone recommend a local network throughput tester?

Specifically, testing throughput between network clients, not to/from the internet.

*Required Features:*

- Test throughput between clients, in both directions
- Quickly determine throughput (aka network thruput)
- Reliable: when there is no network traffic, results should be consistent
- Windows compatible
- No advertising within application
- Works offline (meaning on networks not connected to the internet)
- Does not install any drivers
- Gratis

*Preferred (but **not** required) Features:*

- Portable (no installation)
- Determine latency within network

*Bonus Feature (**not** required):*

- Open-source

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft has a free tool that does what you want.  Its called the [NTttcp Utility](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/NTttcp-Version-528-Now-f8b12769).  I am fairly positive it meets all your listed requirements.

I have used it and it works and is fairly easy to use.

Comment: Thanks!  I'll check it out.  Do you know if it has to install drivers?